# Use .html() to fill out a div created through an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, html

I would like to fill out a div created through an AJAX request using jQuery.

It seems that I can't do it since my new DIV isn't in the DOM at the time I bind the event. Here is my code:

```
function updateNotice(content, type) {
    noticeName.html(content).addClass(type).show("slow");
}
```

`noticeName` is set to `$( "#form-notice" );` in a global variable. But `form-notice` is a div that is sent from another ajax request (called before the one above), how can I fill it? Should I use jQuery.on()? How to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this $( "#form-notice" ); after the html you get from your ajax call is rendered.

```
function updateNotice(content, type) {
noticeName = $( "#form-notice" );
noticeName.html(content).addClass(type).show("slow");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was doing `noticeName = $( "#form-notice" );` right before the Ajax call.. thanks!